# Error response from daemon: Container 494e5de406f3480268fbb9d8e22c41a5bc0ab8aac28d29ac035849d12c1579d5 is not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Hi Team I want to check the container as one of the service was not running, for that, I am giving below command.

docker exec -it 494e5de406f3 /bin/bash

Then I am getting below error

Error response from daemon: Container 494e5de406f3480268fbb9d8e22c41a5bc0ab8aac28d29ac035849d12c1579d5 is not running

Comment: `docker ps -a` check if hash above gets listed as running or exited

Comment: it is showing as Exited

Comment: @hjpotter92 Also a few of my other dockers showing the same error now.

Comment: then you need to check container logs, not execute inside it.